# What's wrong in this sortable table? It was working in jsbin but not in vscode

Tags: javascript

I've been struggling with value inputting into tables and table sorting. Finally I got happy when I got my first project working as inteded in jsbin while writing it, but when I exported it into my VSCode it stopped working. In the snippet initially it works, but after inputting something into the table the sorting stops working. In VSCode while ran on liveserver the table is missing implying that there's something wrong in the js.

This code is based on two examples that I found online and tried to combine them together but I assume they are overlapping each other somehow. Unfortunately I have no idea where to even start looking from.

Also how and where I could insert array.reverse() if I wanted to get reverse sorting?

And I just started learning Javascript, so my knowledge and understanding is really limited. Sorry and thank you.

```js
class Product{
    constructor(name, price, count){
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.count = count;
    }
    static get SORT_ORDER_ASC(){
        return 0;
    }
    static get SORT_ORDER_DESC(){
        return 1;
    }
}

class Shop{
    constructor(){
        this.products = [];
    }
    addProduct (product) {
        this.products.push(product);
    };

    deleteProductByName (productName) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            if (this.products[i].name === productName) {
                this.products.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    };

    get totalProductsPrice () {
        let totalCost = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            totalCost += this.products[i].count * this.products[i].price;
        }
        return totalCost;
    };

    sortProductsByPrice (sortOrder) {
        let rows = document.querySelectorAll("#shopTable .data");
        for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
        {
            this.products[i].name = rows.item(i).toString();
            console.log(this.products[i].name);
        }
        if(sortOrder === 0) {
            this.products.sort();
            this.products.map(t => t.name + "   " + t.price).join("\n");
        }
        else if(sortOrder === 1) {
            this.products.sort();
            this.products.reverse();
            this.products.map(t => t.name + "   " + t.price).join("\n");
        }
        else {
            console.log("The parameter is incorrect");
        }
    };

    show() {
        let rows = document.querySelectorAll("#shopTable .data");
        let tp = document.querySelectorAll("#totalPrice .data");
        for (let i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            let e = rows.item(i);
            e.parentNode.removeChild(e);

        }
        if(document.getElementById("totalPrice") !== null){
            document.getElementById("totalPrice").remove();
        }
        //tp.parentNode.removeChild(tp);

        let table = document.getElementById("shopTable");
        for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            table.innerHTML += `<tbody id="tbProducts"><tr class="data">
                                        <td>${this.products[i].name}</td>
                                        <td>${this.products[i].price}</td>
                                        <td>${this.products[i].count}</td>
                                </tr></tbody>`;
        }
        table.innerHTML += `<tfoot><tr><td id="totalPrice">Total price: ${shop.totalProductsPrice}</td></tr></tfoot>`;
    }
}

let shop = new Shop();

shop.addProduct(new Product("product1", 200, 10));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product2", 500, 1));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product3", 1000, 1));
shop.show();

let btnAdd = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
btnAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    shop.addProduct(new Product(document.getElementById('_add_name').value,
                                parseInt(document.getElementById('_price').value),
                                parseInt(document.getElementById('_count').value)));
    //let tmpTotalPrice =
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = shop.totalProductsPrice;
    shop.show();
}, false);

let btnDlt = document.getElementById("btnDlt");
btnDlt.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    shop.deleteProductByName(document.getElementById('_del_name').value);
    shop.show();
}, false);

/**
 * Inject hyperlinks, into the column headers of sortable tables, which sort
 * the corresponding column when clicked.
 */
var tables = document.querySelectorAll("table.sortable"),
    table,
    thead,
    headers,
    i,
    j;

for (i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
    table = tables[i];

    if (thead = table.querySelector("thead")) {
        headers = thead.querySelectorAll("th");

        for (j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
            headers[j].innerHTML = "<a href='#'>" + headers[j].innerText + "</a>";
        }

        thead.addEventListener("click", sortTableFunction(table));
    }
}

/**
 * Create a function to sort the given table.
 */
function sortTableFunction(table) {
    return function(ev) {
        if (ev.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {
            sortRows(table, siblingIndex(ev.target.parentNode));
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Get the index of a node relative to its siblings — the first (eldest) sibling
 * has index 0, the next index 1, etc.
 */
function siblingIndex(node) {
    var count = 0;

    while (node = node.previousElementSibling) {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}

/**
 * Sort the given table by the numbered column (0 is the first column, etc.)
 */
function sortRows(table, columnIndex) {
    var rows = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr"),
        sel = "thead th:nth-child(" + (columnIndex + 1) + ")",
        sel2 = "td:nth-child(" + (columnIndex + 1) + ")",
        classList = table.querySelector(sel).classList,
        values = [],
        cls = "",
        allNum = true,
        val,
        index,
        node;

    if (classList) {
        if (classList.contains("date")) {
            cls = "date";
        } else if (classList.contains("number")) {
            cls = "number";
        }
    }

    for (index = 0; index < rows.length; index++) {
        node = rows[index].querySelector(sel2);
        val = node.innerText;

        if (isNaN(val)) {
            allNum = false;
        } else {
            val = parseFloat(val);
        }

        values.push({ value: val, row: rows[index] });
    }

    if (cls == "" && allNum) {
        cls = "number";
    }

    if (cls == "number") {
        values.sort(sortNumberVal);
        values = values.reverse();
    } else if (cls == "date") {
        values.sort(sortDateVal);
    } else {
        values.sort(sortTextVal);
    }

    for (var idx = 0; idx < values.length; idx++) {
        table.querySelector("tbody").appendChild(values[idx].row);
    }
}

/**
 * Compare two 'value objects' numerically
 */
function sortNumberVal(a, b) {
    return sortNumber(a.value, b.value);
}

/**
 * Numeric sort comparison
 */
function sortNumber(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

/**
 * Compare two 'value objects' as dates
 */
function sortDateVal(a, b) {
    var dateA = Date.parse(a.value),
        dateB = Date.parse(b.value);

    return sortNumber(dateA, dateB);
}

/**
 * Compare two 'value objects' as simple text; case-insensitive
 */
function sortTextVal(a, b) {
    var textA = (a.value + "").toUpperCase();
    var textB = (b.value + "").toUpperCase();

    if (textA < textB) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (textA > textB) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```css
body { margin-top: 4em; }
table, td, th { border: 1px solid black; margin: auto; }
td, th { padding: 0.5em 1em; }
```

```html
<div id="_shop">
<form id="addForm">
    <label for="_add_name">Name </label><input id="_add_name"><br/><br/>
    <label for="_price">Price </label><input id="_price"><br/><br/>
    <label for="_count">Count </label><input id="_count"><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add"><br/><br/>
</form>
<form id="removeForm">
    <label for="_del_name">Enter Name </label><input id="_del_name"><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" id="btnDlt" value="Delete"><br/><br/>
</form>

<table class="sortable" id="shopTable" align="left">
    <thead>
        <th>Name:</th>
        <th>Price:</th>
        <th>Count:</th>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: Are you using an extension to run JS in VSCode?

Comment: In the snippet when new values added into the table, the sorting doesn't seem to work anymore ulike with the default items.

Im using live server in VSCode and when I put it into a browser window, the table doesn't appear and instead under the delete-button it only shows "Name: Price: Count:" in single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were few things odd with your code. I think, the sorting functionality wasn't implemented in the code you provided. Maybe you exported an older version?

Anyway, here are the few things, that you needed to change:

- In the `sortProductsByPrice()` method, you were setting the `name` property of the product (in `this.products` array) to `rows.item(i)` which was completely off.
  `rows.item(i)` will be the `tr` element at given index. What you wanted to do is set corresponding properties to corresponding `td`'s values (`rows` is array of `tr` and each `tr` has three `td` elements.)
- In the same method, where you sort the array, you need to provide a custom function to sort the products based on their price. This is needed, because JavaScript's default sort sorts the elements alphabetically. Moreover, `this.products` is an array of objects, so you need to sort them based on their `price` property.
- In the event listener of `btnAdd`, you need to call  the `sortProductsByPrice`  method, before calling the `show` method.

```js
class Product{
    constructor(name, price, count){
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.count = count;
    }
    static get SORT_ORDER_ASC(){
        return 0;
    }
    static get SORT_ORDER_DESC(){
        return 1;
    }
}

class Shop{
    constructor(){
        this.products = [];
    }
    addProduct (product) {
        this.products.push(product);
    };

    deleteProductByName (productName) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            if (this.products[i].name === productName) {
                this.products.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    };

    get totalProductsPrice () {
        let totalCost = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            totalCost += this.products[i].count * this.products[i].price;
        }
        return totalCost;
    };

    sortProductsByPrice (sortOrder) {
        let rows = document.querySelectorAll("#shopTable .data");
        for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
        {   
            let td = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td")
            this.products[i].name = td[0].innerHTML;
            this.products[i].price = td[1].innerHTML;
            this.products[i].count = td[2].innerHTML;
            //console.log(this.products[i].name);
        }
        if(sortOrder === 0) {
            this.products.sort((a,b) => a.price - b.price);
            this.products.map(t => t.name + "   " + t.price).join("\n");
        }
        else if(sortOrder === 1) {
            this.products.sort((a,b) => a.price - b.price);
            this.products.reverse();
            this.products.map(t => t.name + "   " + t.price).join("\n");
        }
        else {
            console.log("The parameter is incorrect");
        }
    };

    show() {
        let rows = document.querySelectorAll("#shopTable .data");
        let tp = document.querySelectorAll("#totalPrice .data");
        for (let i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            let e = rows.item(i);
            e.parentNode.removeChild(e);

        }
        if(document.getElementById("totalPrice") !== null){
            document.getElementById("totalPrice").remove();
        }
        //tp.parentNode.removeChild(tp);

        let table = document.getElementById("shopTable");
        for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            table.innerHTML += `<tbody id="tbProducts"><tr class="data">
                                        <td>${this.products[i].name}</td>
                                        <td>${this.products[i].price}</td>
                                        <td>${this.products[i].count}</td>
                                </tr></tbody>`;
        }
        table.innerHTML += `<tfoot><tr><td id="totalPrice">Total price: ${shop.totalProductsPrice}</td></tr></tfoot>`;
    }
}

let shop = new Shop();

shop.addProduct(new Product("product1", 200, 10));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product2", 500, 1));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product3", 1000, 1));
shop.show();

let btnAdd = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
btnAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    shop.addProduct(new Product(document.getElementById('_add_name').value,
                                parseInt(document.getElementById('_price').value),
                                parseInt(document.getElementById('_count').value)));
    //let tmpTotalPrice =
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = shop.totalProductsPrice;
    shop.sortProductsByPrice(0)
    shop.show();
}, false);

let btnDlt = document.getElementById("btnDlt");
btnDlt.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    shop.deleteProductByName(document.getElementById('_del_name').value);
    shop.show();
}, false);

/**
 * Inject hyperlinks, into the column headers of sortable tables, which sort
 * the corresponding column when clicked.
 */
var tables = document.querySelectorAll("table.sortable"),
    table,
    thead,
    headers,
    i,
    j;

for (i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
    table = tables[i];

    if (thead = table.querySelector("thead")) {
        headers = thead.querySelectorAll("th");

        for (j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
            headers[j].innerHTML = "<a href='#'>" + headers[j].innerText + "</a>";
        }

        thead.addEventListener("click", sortTableFunction(table));
    }
}

/**
 * Create a function to sort the given table.
 */
function sortTableFunction(table) {
    return function(ev) {
        if (ev.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {
            sortRows(table, siblingIndex(ev.target.parentNode));
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Get the index of a node relative to its siblings — the first (eldest) sibling
 * has index 0, the next index 1, etc.
 */
function siblingIndex(node) {
    var count = 0;

    while (node = node.previousElementSibling) {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}

/**
 * Sort the given table by the numbered column (0 is the first column, etc.)
 */
function sortRows(table, columnIndex) {
    var rows = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr"),
        sel = "thead th:nth-child(" + (columnIndex + 1) + ")",
        sel2 = "td:nth-child(" + (columnIndex + 1) + ")",
        classList = table.querySelector(sel).classList,
        values = [],
        cls = "",
        allNum = true,
        val,
        index,
        node;

    if (classList) {
        if (classList.contains("date")) {
            cls = "date";
        } else if (classList.contains("number")) {
            cls = "number";
        }
    }

    for (index = 0; index < rows.length; index++) {
        node = rows[index].querySelector(sel2);
        val = node.innerText;

        if (isNaN(val)) {
            allNum = false;
        } else {
            val = parseFloat(val);
        }

        values.push({ value: val, row: rows[index] });
    }

    if (cls == "" && allNum) {
        cls = "number";
    }

    if (cls == "number") {
        values.sort(sortNumberVal);
        values = values.reverse();
    } else if (cls == "date") {
        values.sort(sortDateVal);
    } else {
        values.sort(sortTextVal);
    }

    for (var idx = 0; idx < values.length; idx++) {
        table.querySelector("tbody").appendChild(values[idx].row);
    }
}

/**
 * Compare two 'value objects' numerically
 */
function sortNumberVal(a, b) {
    return sortNumber(a.value, b.value);
}

/**
 * Numeric sort comparison
 */
function sortNumber(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

/**
 * Compare two 'value objects' as dates
 */
function sortDateVal(a, b) {
    var dateA = Date.parse(a.value),
        dateB = Date.parse(b.value);

    return sortNumber(dateA, dateB);
}

/**
 * Compare two 'value objects' as simple text; case-insensitive
 */
function sortTextVal(a, b) {
    var textA = (a.value + "").toUpperCase();
    var textB = (b.value + "").toUpperCase();

    if (textA < textB) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (textA > textB) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```css
body { margin-top: 4em; }
table, td, th { border: 1px solid black; margin: auto; }
td, th { padding: 0.5em 1em; }
```

```html
<div id="_shop">
<form id="addForm">
    <label for="_add_name">Name </label><input id="_add_name"><br/><br/>
    <label for="_price">Price </label><input id="_price"><br/><br/>
    <label for="_count">Count </label><input id="_count"><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add"><br/><br/>
</form>
<form id="removeForm">
    <label for="_del_name">Enter Name </label><input id="_del_name"><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" id="btnDlt" value="Delete"><br/><br/>
</form>

<table class="sortable" id="shopTable" align="left">
    <thead>
        <th>Name:</th>
        <th>Price:</th>
        <th>Count:</th>
    </thead>
</table>
```